# Variable variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variable-variables

In PHP I can mess around with variable variables and I'm wondering if I can do the same in JavaScript.

I want to create a new object with a property which's name is based on the value of a variable.

```
if ( obj.name === 'foo' ) {
    var data = { foo: value };
}
if ( obj.name === 'bar' ) {
    var data = { bar: value };
}
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this without using `eval()`? Something like:

```
var data = { obj.name: value };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {};
data[obj.name] = value;
```

You can read some more about js objects [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 3):

Objects in JavaScript are simply hash maps. You can access members by indexing with their names. For your problem you can use

```
var data = {};
data[obj.name] = value;
```

I've used this to implement a dynamic dispatch mechanism for arithmetic operations on different numerical types as described [here](http://www.thusspakeak.com/ak/2013/05/01-climbing-mount-impractical.html).